is it correct to say "can you stop clinking the cup of coffee"?
There is a cup and there is coffee in it.
A boy hits it with a spoon repeatedly.
is it correct to say "can you stop clinking the cup of coffee"?
I looked up "cup" in the dictionary. And "a cup" can mean:

1- a physical cup
2- the content of a cup

With the first meaning, I only see "a tea cup" or "a coffee cup" but not "a cup of tea"
With the second meaning, I often see "a cup of tea" or "a cup of coffee".
So, when saying "clink the cup of coffee", we mean to clink the content, which does not make sense.
we can clink "the cup" but not "the cup of coffee" right?
Is that correct?

Right. You'd stop at "cup" and not include "of coffee".

I would (slightly) rephrase with "that": can you stop clinking that cup of coffee!? But, "cup of coffee" is perfectly fine (with either "the" or "that"). Slightly shorter would be can you stop clinking that coffee cup!? It's very common for a waitress to ask Would you like a cup of coffee with your meal?

The question is building on the assumption that one turn of phrase invariably ties itself to one definition of the word; which is not the case. This assumption then goes off the rails when it becomes the basis for your understanding of further turns of phrase (as evidenced by you claim that "when saying "clink the cup of coffee", we mean to clink the content", based not on your understanding of the language but on blind application of your assumed rule). This undermines the value that you get from a direct answer to your question.

One might argue that it's slightly more correct to say stop clinking the coffee cup but cup of coffee often is used to refer to both the cup and contents together - so either phrase would be easily understood here.

I'd say the simplest expression, the one a native speaker would use, is "stop clinking" or "stop that clinking" -- the cup isn't important at all. "Stop making that noise" is another common phrasing. But yes, it's fine to say "stop clinking that cup of coffee" -- understandable and not ungrammatical, in my opinion.

You can absolutely say this, though you probably wouldn't really refer to the contents of the cup in an irritating situation; you simply want to get the point across and need only reference the cup itself. Both its contents or its design (teacups and coffee cups have different forms) don't really matter.
While I can understand the distinction you're making from your research, nobody would think anything of "can you stop clinking the cup?" vs. "can you stop clinking the cup of X?".
All variations would sound natural enough to say but, again, you probably wouldn't bother being so specific about the object itself, just the annoyance of the act.

I think either of these variants would be far more likely than having "the cup of coffee" as direct object of the verb "clink".

Could you stop clinking your spoon like that?
Could you stop clinking your spoon on the cup?

The cup appears in a prepositional phrase and the spoon is the direct object.
Idiomatic "like that" in this context can express annoyance.

+1 — this is the most important point.  But to combine it with the OP’s question about “cup of coffee”: something like “Could you stop clinking your spoon on the cup of coffee?” would be perfectly correct, though slightly odd in context (since it’s already clear what cup is in question); but it would be completely natural to describe the scene later as “He was clinking his spoon on a cup of coffee…”


is it correct to say "can you stop clinking the cup of coffee"?

It's not wrong in the sense that there are no grammatical errors, but nobody would really say that in a situation like this. It wouldn't really be idiomatic (or natural).  However, it would still be understood.
It would be far more common to say something like "Please stop doing that" or "Please don't do that" or "Stop it, please". There's no need to mention how the sound is being made or the object itself, because the meaning would be clear from the context or situation itself.  You could also remove the word please to make it a less polite and more direct order, depending on the level of annoyance.
Also, a teacup or coffee cup is a cup for drinking tea/coffee.  A cup of tea/coffee is a cup containing tea/coffee - a serving of tea/coffee in a cup.

We didn't get the 'please' thing when I was a kid, and the possibility of a 'thick ear' meant that cup-clinking was just, well, not done. But It was a long time ago (i was eight in 1960).

@MichaelHarvey. Yeah, or more often than not, my father would just shout my name very loudly if I was doing anything wrong or annoying!

Table manners, it was called. Family mealtimes are often a kind of arena in which cultural values are transmitted from generation to generation. My father was very strict, maybe a bit more than most. Holding the knife properly. Holding the fork properly ('you're holding a fork, not a spade!'). Chewing properly. Not talking with the mouth full. And so on.

The problem with "stop clinking the cup of coffee" is that it is very specific. You don't want to have to follow it up with "now stop clinking the cup of tea"...

The focus of the question appears to ask whether a spoon hits a "tea/coffee cup" or "cup of tea/coffee". A teacup can be empty, so striking it with a teaspoon is perfectly possible but you cannot strike tea or coffee without it being in a cup (or mug).
Clink is not only a verb, it's a noun, too. We hear the clink of a teacup resting on a saucer; the teaspoon stirring sugar in a china cup makes a clinking or tinkling  sound, but when an action is repeated and annoying, I would use the verb tap or hit. A tap hints at a gentler sound than hit, and could suggest someone absentmindedly stirring a cup while lost in their thoughts. Someone hitting a cup/mug/bowl might suggest they are doing it out of spite, anger, or to draw someone's attention. I say could because it's up to the speaker or writer to choose the word(s) they prefer.
Examples of usage that include "spoon" and "cup of tea"

She could hear the policeman outside, stirring a cup of tea, the spoon tapping against the side of the cup.
Absolution by Caro Ramsay


reached for the cup of tea on the table next to him. Inspecting the mug, he took a short sip and confirmed the obvious: it was too cold to drink. He put the mug back down on the tabletop. Bending forward, he then took out the spoon, tapping it on the cup's rim  rim while tea dripped from it, and put it on the tabletop next to the mug.
Blind.Faith 2.0.50 by Tomasz Tatum (their only work)


When she had finished her cup of tea, she lay back in her chair, tapping it with the spoon."
The Little Street-Sweeper (1865)


She was light-headed from hunger, having had nothing all day but a cup of tea at Leamington station, and her head was aching violently. Olive didn't join them in sitting down. She took a long, considering slurp of tea and clinked the cup back down hard on its saucer.
Poppy Day by Annie Murray


…stirring sugar into cup after cup of tea, watching my father through the window. The spoon hitting the cup over and over again makes a sound like a little bell.
The Best American Short Stories 2015

Conclusion:
It seems that characters in novels tend not to tap, hit or clink their cup of tea but on the rim or the side of the cup.

Examples with the verbs: hit, clink, tap, with tea cup or tea cup

My mother had a lot of emotional difficulties. She would sometimes sit at the kitchen table slowly stirring her teacup and endlessly staring out the window.  The spoon would clink on the teacup – clink-clink, clink-clink – each time it went round.
[…] there's a certain kind of clinking sound that my body strongly reacts to. Even if I'm stirring my own teacup that sound can make me shudder.
Cultivating Spiritual Maturity  by Lalitha Thomas


Sandhya absentmindedly stirred her tea. Her husband tried to ignore the never-ending sound of the spoon hitting the teacup. When the sound didn't stop for two full minutes, he sighed and lowered the book he was trying to concentrate on.
Second Chances by Shreya Das


Ashley was tapping her tea cup with her spoon and staring into space…
The Tears of Mary by Scott Baker Sweeney.


More smiling and nodding as Deidra stirred in some sugar. "Historic downtown Petaluma seems like the perfect fit," Sistine said, trying not to sound schmaltzy.
Deidre tapped the spoon against her teacup and pointed it at Sistine.
Tap: a love story by Tracy Ewens


When Olga had told me Elena would talk to me I assumed she would give me fifteen minutes or half an hour at most, and that we would probably interrupted by friends or cell phones. I expected curt answers, reticence, distracting behaviors such as tapping her tea spoon or gazing out the window. But two hours have passed.
Dreams of the Solo Trapeze by Mark Schreiber.

Conclusion:
Characters in novels will hit, tap, and clink teacups (or tea cups)

A suggestion, by no means the only or the best.  The OP could say

Will you (please) stop tapping against the cup?


I wouldn't use "tap" or "hit" to describe the action and sound of a metal spoon clinking against a ceramic cup. A "tapping" sound is not like that spoon-against-ceramic sound. There can be a tapping on a door or wall. Your "literary" examples do not reflect normal speech.  It's not impossible, of course, but "clinking" is much more likely by orders of magnitude when referring to the  sound.

@TimR That's your preference, and I respect that but these examples are taken from Google books, and the spoon is metal and the cup is ceramic, china, porcelain,  or even stoneware but definitely not cardboard (or plastic)  that are sold in Starbucks or Costa. The examples sound perfectly normal to me, but I'll concede they are descriptive just like the onomatopoeic  clink which  is fairly literary, I don't think your average American 20-year-old would say "clink". Furthermore I saw loads  of examples where variations of the verb "tap" (tapped, was tapping) were used.

No, it's not my preference but what I think to be the case among native speakers, who would not use "tap" of the sound of a metal spoon makes on a teacup or coffee cup.  Clink is not literary at all; almost any child has the word in their vocabulary.

It is your preference as a native American speaker, and I did not say "clink" is not used. It is a fine word, perhaps better suited to glasses, and as an added bonus it is onomatopoeic–I even cited examples of its usage. But when I think of "a boy [that] hits it with a spoon repeatedly" then hitting and/or tapping  are perfectly fine words and do the job. I think practically every child from the age of four is familiar with the word "hit". Besides, the OP could say…  I am not dictating anything to anyone.

I think we're talking past each other.  Your choices (tap, hit) are grammatical and there would be no problem understanding your request that someone should stop tapping their spoon on their teacup. I'm just saying don't rely on literary texts  as indicators of what people actually say on a daily basis, especially ones that do not faithfully capture native speech in their dialog. Citing Faulkner for attestation of US southern speech is one thing. Citing a novel where the name "Sistine" appears in a sentence close to the word "schmalzy" is another.

Further, "tapping" is a deliberate action, whereas "clinking" can be a byproduct of stirring a metal spoon around in a cup in a less than delicate way, but not really intentional.

So you're agreeing with me? I said as much in the introduction of my answer. The difference between stirring a cup, placing a cup on its saucer and someone repeatedly tapping/hitting the side of a cup, which can be annoying to hear.

I am saying that you would be understood, not that "tapping" is the most apt choice.  You can tap something with your fingertip almost silently.

The internet is amazing. An essay on the different ways to describe tapping a cup with a spoon. And then a lengthy semi-heated debate about the correct words. FWIW, 'tapping' is the verb I automatically selected, before reading the said semi-heated debate. FWIW#2 I recall my school teacher gently berating me in 1983 for clicking pen on a desk, and the phrase she used was 'Fred2: TAP NOT'.

My father always (and I mean always), having added two teaspoons of sugar, used to stir his 'traditional' cup of tea (i.e. in a cup that sat in a saucer), and then play a little tune on the cup and saucer (tink-tinkly-tink on the cup then tink-tink on the saucer) before placing the spoon in the saucer. Without fail. My mother used to grimace, and woe betide any of the kids who copied him (yes, we drank tea from age about six).

While what you say would be understood, when you say "the cup of coffee" it tends to emphasize the fact that the cup contains coffee. So at a restaurant you might order a cup of coffee.
If your emphasis is on the physical cup, it's more common to say "the coffee cup", or just "the cup" if it's obvioius which cup you mean (there's no other cup being clinked).

Yes, if they're clinking the cup.
Yes, I would say that it's a correct sentence, but it doesn't mean quite what you think it does. It would refer to someone clinking the whole cup against something else, like another cup or a metal sink, not someone clinking a spoon around inside it.

"Will you please stop the clinking"?
spoons and cups and the contents of cups are irrelevant unless there are multiple clinking objects clinking against multiple targets.

Two issues:

“A cup of coffee” is the contents of the cup.  If you want to refer to the vessel, it’s “a coffee cup”.
“clink”, if it’s a verb at all, is intransitive.  The action of tapping the spoon on the coffee cup clinks or produces a clink.


I disagree with your claim that "“A cup of coffee” is the contents of the cup".  Where I live, it's often the cup and the contents.  If someone asked me to put their cup of coffee onto their desk for them, they would definitely expect the coffee still to be in the cup.

@TobySpeight — as a practical matter, any liquid usually must be delivered in a container.  To address the question of what the phrase “a cup of coffee” means, consider two scenarios: (1) you order a cup of coffee at restaurant and are served any empty cup; (2) you order a cup of coffee, drink the contents and try to leave with the cup.  “A [container] of [liquid]” is usually interpreted as “a [container]-worth of [liquid]”, with the container sort of thrown in...

What's the relevance of Scenario 1?  That seems to be just the cup, not the cup+contents.  I partially agree with the final sentence of your comment - sometimes it's the contents which get the emphasis.  But in my experience, that -worth isn't usually elided (for instance if I'm offering the remaining one cup's worth from my vacuum flask).  Perhaps different amongst your peers?
